# Error when using bulk insert into Azure SQL DB when using stored proc in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to importdata from a local CSV file into an Azure database.  the idea is to allow the customer to do bulk inserts into the system using a preformatted CSV file.

The code I am using is:

```
    BULK INSERT tmp_Import_Truck
   FROM 'C:\ImportFrom\ImportData.csv'
   WITH
     (
        FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
      )
```

The problem is that I am getting an eror that it cannot open the file.

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "C:\ImportFrom\ImportData.csv" could not be opened. Operating system
>   error code (null).

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: This path is on your local computer, while BULK INSERT expects file on the server. Which obviously can't happen with Azure SQL DB.

Comment: Iam running SSMS locally, the connect to Azure is remote- can I not bulk insert form thelocalmachine to Azure?  If not, how do I get the data to the Azure server (never used Azure before)

Comment: Yes, the path specified in bulk insert will be opened by the SQL Server engine, i.e. it must be on the server. SQL Server can't read files on your disk. You need to use BCP utility (as I showed you in my answer bellow) or write your program to perform bulk insert operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `bulk insert` in Azure SQL DB with file name, because it should be on the SQL Server machine.

You can use however [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) utility executed on your computer, to bulk copy this file to Azure SQL:

```
bcp database.dbo.table in C:\ImportFrom\ImportData.csv
    -S yourserver.database.windows.net
    -U someusername -P strongpassword
```